# Ruby: wait for any child process to finish

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to wait for any (not all!) child process to finish? I am writing a Rake task that spawns several child processes and I want to start an action as soon as the first child process is finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call

```
Process.wait
```

With no arguments. This waits for any child process to terminate (see [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-wait))

You can also wait for children of a specific process group - possibly useful if you need more control.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be, you can find if a process is still running using something like:

```
begin
  Process.getpgid( pid )
  true
rescue Errno::ESRCH
  false
end
```

Now you can put a check on the process(polling), once its over, you can trigger other processes as desired.